# Why are my 7.1 computer speakers (Creative Labs Inspire P7800) making weird sputtering sounds?

Tags: speakers

This sputtering sound occurs whether the speakers are connected or disconnected from my computer.

The sound is a not a high pitched sound, but a lower pitch that with a constant volume loudness. It is clearly pulsing with moments of silence and equally long moments of audible sound. Makes about 2-3 sputtering pulses per second.

The sound goes away when I increase my volume to 70-100%. If I decrease my volume knob from 70% down to 0% then the sputtering sound get louder. Cranking volume knob up makes the sputtering sound quieter till the sputtering disappears completely. Altering the bass levels knob does not affect the sputtering sound.

Answer (score 1):

My wifi router (TP-link AX1800 WiFi 6 router) standing 15 cm away from the subwoofer was the culprit.

I suspect it is the antennae of the router causing electromagnetic interference when placed too close to the subwoofer. The sputtering sound is loud at first, but moving the router away will make the sound quieter till it disappears completely at around 4-5 feet. My cable modem, Voip phone device, and two 6 outlet power strips were not the culprit as they also stand 15 cm from the subwoofer unit.

Hope you got long ethernet cables.

Comment: I wonder if ferrite beads around the subwoofer cables would help. I